# How to remove program project path from the run window of CLion

Tags: c++, c, clion

I don't want the project file path in the run windows of CLion. But I don't know how to remove it.[Here the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvtZ6.png)

Comment: It's not project path. It's executable itself. AFAIK there it no such option to hide it from Run Tool Window. Could you please explain the reason you want to avoid it?

Comment: I just wanted the main output portion, not the path of executable.

Comment: The Run window also contains return status: `Process finished with exit code 0`. So it very far from you want to see, The best way to achieve your goal is redirect output to file.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `clrscr()`:

```
clrscr(); //this function will clear the screen before the statements
```